# delete and update a object of associated model using ajax and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models. lets say `defects` and `products`.

`product has_many :defects`

`defect belongs_to :product`

1) I am listing all the associated defects of a product in the show page

I want to include an `edit` and `delete` action for the defects in the product show page. 
By default the delete action is deleting the product as the destroy function is called on the product ( `@product.destroy`) in the controller.How to delete a selected defect?

2) For creating the defects i have included the below js script (`create.js.erb`) in the defects controller

```
   var html = "<p> <%= @product.defect.try(:defect_description) </p>"
$('#added').append(html);
```

This wouldn't work as the association between the two is has many.How to append the defect that was entered ?
 I am using the form in the product show page

This is the product show page code where i am listing the defects and adding

```
<button class="mybtn">Defects </button>
          </div>
          <div id="clicked">
            <% if @product.defects.present? %>
          <% @product.defects.each do |defect|%>
          <p> <%= defect.try(:defect_description) %>  <%= link_to 'Delete', defect, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete ?"},class: "btn btn-danger btn-xs" %></td></p> 
          <% end %>
          <%= link_to "Add Defects",new_product_defect_path(@product.id),class:'btn btn-sm btn-success',remote:true%>
          <% else %>
             <p id="new_defect"> No defects found for this product </p>
              <%= link_to "Add Defects",new_product_defect_path(@product.id),class:'btn btn-sm btn-success',remote:true%>
           <%end%>
           </div>
```

Comment: Could you please add your show page code

Comment: Extract your view content to a partial and upon add/delete, just render the partial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**products/show.html.erb**

```
<div id="clicked">
   <%= render 'product_defects' %>
</div>
```

**products/_product_defects.html.erb**

```
<% if @product.defects.present? %>
    <% @product.defects.each do |defect|%>
      <p>
         <%= defect.try(:defect_description) %>
         <%= link_to 'Delete', defect, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete ?"},class: "btn btn-danger btn-xs" %></td>
      </p> 
    <% end %>

    <%= link_to "Add Defects",new_product_defect_path(@product.id),class:'btn btn-sm btn-success',remote:true%>
<% else %>
      <p id="new_defect"> No defects found for this product </p>
      <%= link_to "Add Defects",new_product_defect_path(@product.id),class:'btn btn-sm btn-success',remote:true%>
<% end %>
```

When you hit `Add Defects` button, an ajax request will be sent to your `DefectsController's create action`. You need to get the product for which the defect is to be added and render the `_product_defects.html.erb` as follows:

**defects/create.js.erb**

```
$("#clicked").html("<%= render 'products/product_defects' %>");
```

Comment: I tried it, i got a template missing error, also when i checked my server logs i t show processing create as js and has done the insert and then also shows  processing show as js. why is that?

Comment: @PallaviHegde Can you please add your complete stack trace ?

Comment: but the partial didnt work though, i added the code again

Answer (score 1):

To list all the defects for the product with edit/delete actions, in the product show page, you'd have something like:

```
<% @product.defects.each do |defect| %>
  <%= defect.description %>
  <%= button_to 'Edit', edit_product_defect_path(@product, defect)
  <%= button_to 'Delete', product_defect_path(@product, defect), method: :delete
<% end %>
```

As regards the defect that has been created, you should have access to that defect so you can amend your append statement accordingly.

```
var html = "<p> <%= @defect.defect_description </p>";
html += "<%= button_to 'Edit', edit_product_defect_path(@product, defect)";
$('#added').append(html);
```

Comment: i want to add a defect through ajax.. so how do i get access to the defect

Comment: When you create the defect, you have access to it. What happens when you click the link new_product_defect_path(@product.id). Presumably you display a form which submits to the defects_controller create action. That's where you have access to the new defect.

Comment: okay.. i tried it.. but its getting added only after a page refresh

Comment: do you have a div with an id = "added"

Comment: You should post your code that made it work so others with similar problems can view the working solution. If either of the answers helped you get to the working solution, it would be good if you up voted them.